# Js+Ajax. Как остановить повторное выполнение скрипта?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Реализована такая схема:

1. HTML форма + Ajax скрипт.
2. В форме вводится значения и по клику кнопки Ajax запрашивает PHP файл
3. В PHP файле список значений формате "Значение => Путь к скрипту"
4. Вводим значение => Ajax запрашивает это значение у PHP => выполняется соответствующий значению скрипт php => выводится результат обратно на HTML с помощью AJAX.

В первом скрипте (1.php) помимо php команд я прописал тестовый js скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(1111);
</script>
```

И по запросу значения я получаю диалоговое окно `1111` и результат выполнения php. Это нормально.

Проблема в том, что данный js скрипт как-будто прописывается в память и при дальнейшем запросе других значений (без перезагрузки страницы) он продолжает вылазить и в *2.php* и в *3.php* и т.д.

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Включаю режим телепатии (мой любимый режим):

```js
function clickFullHTML() {
  var conv = $("#converse").html();
  $("#converse").html(conv + " more content ");
}

function clickAppendHTML() {
  $("#converse").append(" more content ");
}
```

```css
div#converse{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="converse"> DIV with script
  <script>
    alert(111);
  </script>
</div>
<br/>
<button onclick="clickFullHTML()">Full HTML reassignment</button>
<br/><br/>
<button onclick="clickAppendHTML()">Append HTML</button>
```

Спасибо за внимание. Наши представления - каждый четверг.

Выключаю режим телепатии.

**Update**

Как выяснилось, мои телепатические способности меня (*опять*) не подвели.

> здесь мой скрипт ... https://toster.ru/q/509677, может это внесет
>   ясность

Вы делаете именно то, что я воспроизвел в `clickFullHTML` выше.

Здесь:

```
conv = $("#converse").html();
```

и здесь:

```
$("#converse").html(conv + ...);
```

Comment: Igor Спасибо, но немног не то наверное..) Вот здесь скрипт мой показан https://toster.ru/q/509677, может это внесет ясность..